# Show multiple rows from a plist in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, plist, rows

I have a problem, I'm creating a quiz game and have a few questions long and need to break up in five rows and not knowing I'm doing this, how can I fix this, I get this question a plist and I make a [question setString : [NSString stringWithFormat :@"%@", dictPerguntas]]; to display on screen, need help! Thanks.

Comment: can i assume that your dictPerguntas has 5 questions in it? Or is it one question but its a long question??

Comment: I'm sorry but my answer was in front and did not see, I actually wanted to display a query on several lines, and have found how to do this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but my answer was in front and did not see, I actually wanted to display a query on several lines, and have found how to do this, thanks for the help.

If anyone is looking for the solution.

```
CCLabel *question = [CCLabel labelWithString:@"Question"                                          dimensions:CGSizeMake(220, 100)                                          alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter                                        fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:16];

question.color = ccc3(0,0,0);
[question setPosition:ccp(160, 365)];
[self addChild: question];
[question setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dictQuestions]];
```